# How format a special TD in a Table?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I have here two table which have neither class nor ID and what I also can not edit.

But I can edit the CSS of them.

How can I format the three TD´s of the second table (with the content "xxx , yyy, zzz") in CSS.
Does possibly nested "nth-child" or something like that help?
I've tried a few things, but it always affects both tables. But it should only affect the second table.

```html
 <h4>sdkfjsdhgfksd</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Market</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>4444</td>
    <td>55555</td>
    <td>666666</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>tzutututzuutzu</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Market</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>xxx</td>
    <td>yyy</td>
    <td>zzz</td>
    <td>666666</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: `table:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(3)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
table:nth-of-type(2) /* select second table */
tr:nth-of-type(2) /* select second row of the table */
td:nth-child(3), /* select third child of the row */
table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(4),
table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h4>sdkfjsdhgfksd</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Market</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>333</td>
    <td>4444</td>
    <td>55555</td>
    <td>666666</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<h4>tzutututzuutzu</h4>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>This</td>
    <td>Little</td>
    <td>Piggy</td>
    <td>Went</td>
    <td>To</td>
    <td>Market</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>22</td>
    <td>xxx</td>
    <td>yyy</td>
    <td>zzz</td>
    <td>666666</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, this Works perfekt. Also the shortened version: table:nth-of-type(2) tr:nth-of-type(2) td:nth-child(n+3):nth-child(-n+5)
{background-color: red;}  :-)